# Problema de formatação ao injetar data no atributo datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Preciso atribuir a data atual num campo `datetime` de um parágrafo, para isso eu implementei:

```
...

var newDate = new Date(),
date = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + newDate.getDate() + " " + newDate.getHours() + ":" + newDate.getMinutes() + ":" + newDate.getSeconds();

$(".container").append("<p id=msg" + id + " class='message' datetime=" + date + ">" + userMessage + "</p>");

...
```

Ao inspecionar no browser as informações inseridas estão formatadas incorretamente:

```
<p id="msg1" class="message" datetime="2015-2-23" 11:26:48="">teste</p>
```

O que preciso corrigir para que a resultado seja assim?:

```
<p id="msg1" class="message" datetime="2015-2-23 11:26:48">teste</p>
```

Comment: Não entendi porque essa pergunta levou -1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As respostas anteriores irão lhe ajudar. Mas, para evitar confusões e deixar o código mais legível, tente sempre usar o `append` da seguinte forma:

```
$(".container").append(
    $('<p>').attr({
        id: 'msg'+id,
        datetime: date
        }).addClass('message').text(userMessage)
)
```

Comment: muito boa a solução. +1 pela organização!

Answer (score 2):

Você não está abrindo e fechando as aspas de forma correta para o id e para o datetime, pois as mesmas conflitam com a declaração do append. Substitua as aspas (`"`) por apostrofos (`'`), ou adicione uma barra (`\`) a cada aspas que vá circundar uma string do programa.

```
$(".container").append('<p id="msg' + id + '" class="message" datetime="' + date + '">"' + userMessage + '"</p>"');
```

#### ou

```
$(".container").append("<p id=\"msg" + id + "\" class=\"message\" datetime=\"" + date + "\">" + userMessage + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenar strings acaba sempre em algum ponto gerando uma certa confusão. É por isso que, quando essa tarefa se torna constante, eu costumo adicionar um método no objeto `String` do `javascript`, para facilitar esse tipo de trabalho.

Veja:

```
(function(String){
   // adicionamos o método format a qualquer string do javascript
    String.prototype.format = function () {

        var args = arguments;

        return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(match, index){

            return args[index];

        }).toString();

    }

})(String);
```

E posteriormente utilizamos da seguinte forma.

```
var data = "<p id='msg{0}' class='message' datetime='{1}'>{2}</p>".format(id, date, userMessage )
$(".container").append(data);
```

Nesse caso, o número envolvido por chaves representa o valor do argumento, começando de `0`, no método `format`.

Veja esse exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tjyz89oy/)